# I am unable to remove my Schlage door handle

Tags: lock

The Schlage door handle has a semi circle Hole instead of the small round holes I see on new door handles and I am unable to remove handle with pins, small screw driver and Allen ranch. Any suggestions. I think the door handles were installed in around 2004. I wish I could attach picture.

Comment: You can [edit] your question, the click the "sun & mountain" button above the text entry box to attach a picture. Or, if you're on a computer, simply drag & drop the picture into the text box.